# How can I get the next day name in python

Tags: python

I tried this code but it's only giving me the current day name.

How can I get the next day name?

```py
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now()

days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
a = days[d.weekday()]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use strftime:

```
(d + datetime.timedelta(1)).strftime('%A')
>>> 'Wednesday'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a number of days to a given date to produce a new `datetime` object for that date:

```
tomorrow = d +datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print(days[d.weekday()])
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step: calculate tomorrow day. Second step: get the name of tomorrow's day

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now()
tomorrow = d + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
a = days[tomorrow.weekday()]
```

Answer (score 1):

First add one day to your date with `timedelta` object, then get the name of the day with `strftime('%A')`.

```
import datetime

next_day = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print(next_day.strftime('%A'))
```

That's it. There is no need to have extra `days` list and use the index (`d.weekday() + 1`), but if you want to do that, you should also use `%` operator(@Anentropic mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70666727/13944524)) to prevent `IndexError` when your day is "Sunday". In that case `.weekday()` will return `6` and the `days[d.weekday() + 1]` will raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a hardcoded array, use [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

```py
import datetime

tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

print(tomorrow.strftime('%A'))
# Wednesday
```

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCElsSS1JDM3lYurJD83v6gov1zBFi6oB2LoleSnJFZqaCpoI8RBREpqTkmiBlCq2NZQk4uroCgzr0QDZohecUlRGkiVhrqqo7qm5v//AA)

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

Just get the next number in the array because the current day get the current:

```
d = datetime.datetime.now()
# Monday

a = days[d.weekday()+1]
# Tuesday
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use the modulo operator `%` to wraparound our lookup in the days list:

```py
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now()

days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

today_name = days[d.weekday()]

tomorrow_name = days[(d.weekday() + 1) % 7]
```

https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations